# Adding a value to a serialized dictionary without loading it

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Here is the description of the problem:

**My problem**: My goal is to add a new value to a serialized dictionary in python (the serialization is done using the Pickle module and the dictionary is saved in a text file) without loading the dictionary first from the file, adding the new value and rewriting the serialized dictionary to the file.

**My current code**:

```
def write(key, value): # parameters for the new dictionary variable
    with open(file_loc, "r+") as file:
        text=file.read()  # load the content of the database
        _dict= pickle.loads(text) # translate the serialized data to dictionary form
        _dict[key]=value  # the new variable added to the serialized dictionary
        file.seek(0)  # get to the first index-rewrite text
        file.write(pickle.dumps(_dict) ) # write the new information to the file
```

**What I've tried:** I know that this can be done using Regex, but I'm looking for a way that may be more efficient. I have looked at Pickle's documentation and at questions similar to mine but didn't find a solution that meets my need.

Comment: I'm not going to say this isn't possible, but is not an easy one. Without pickle loading it, you would still need to load the full contents of the dictionary into memory, and would still need full knowledge of the structure of the dictionary. I doubt you will find an answer better than Regex; but I question why you would want to do this. If you give the scenario, I'm sure someone can suggest a better solution than manipulating pickled text directly.

Comment: I am using the dictionary as a database. As a database, it might get large and thus reloading it might be inefficient...

Comment: Maybe your real problem is: why don't you use a database?

Comment: I have to use a dictionary for an exercise, I would use a database otherwise.

Comment: That is a fun problem to work on. Then I would recommend not using pickling at all. Instead, create your own schema for how data will be stored in the db. You could have one file that allows mapping from a key to a line number. This file would get periodically re-organized to sort the keys, and make lookups more efficient. Then, in the other file, you would use newlines to delaminate between data, where the line number is what's referenced in the first file. It sounds complicated, but much less so than parsing pickles. EDIT: you would also create your own scheme for reading in the dictionary.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it with pickling?

Comment: The format of the data in a pickle file isn't publicly documented, potentially varys from version to version of Python, and within a version there are several different "protocols" (which result in different data formatting) that can be used (some of which are binary). For these reasons, I would say what you want to do isn't feasible nor a good idea. Depending on what's in the dictionary, some other format like JSON might be a better approach — and since they're text files, would be easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

```
def write(key, value):
  num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('content.txt'))
  serializaed_value = my_custom_serializer(value)
  with open("content.txt", "a") as content_file:
    content_file.write("appended text")
    content_file.write("\n")
  with open("key.txt", "a") as key_file:
    key_file.write("{}:{}\n".format(key, num_lines))

def read(key):
  with open("key.txt", "r") as key_file:
    line_num = None
    while line_num == None:
      for line in key_file:
        if key in line:
          line_num = line.split(":")[1]
      if line_num == None:
        raise Exception()
    with open("content.txt", "a") as content_file:
      for i, line in enumerate(content_file):
        if i == line_num:
           return my_custom_deserializer(line)
      raise Exception("Line number not found")
```

Then, you just need to implement the serializer and deserializer. And, since it's your goal, you can use pickle for that part.

EDIT: This code is untested, and has very little error handling. It is also meant to be used with one, and only one, application running against the content and key files at a time.

Also, if you choose to use the pickler for the serialization and deserialization part, base64 encode the value after pickle dumping, and decode prior to pickle loading. This will help avoid issues with unwanted characters in your content.txt file.